# changing the text color of the child class of a sibling of another class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sass, compass-sass

How to create that conditional check to perform a certain action? Ex:

```
<h1 class = "parentclass1">
     <p class = "childclass1"></p> <!--- This child class is conditional--->
</h1>
<h1 class = "parentclass2">
     <p class = "childclass2"></p>
</h1>
```

I want to change the text color of "childclass2" only if the "parentclass1" has "childclass1, otherwise, ignore it. (The following code has id name instead of class for the parent class name)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  if($("h5").parent().find("hide")){
    #price-field .money {color:red};
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h5 class="compare-at-price js" style="font-size: 14px;">
    <span class="money" style="font-size: 14px;">$60</span>
    </h5>
<h3 class="custom-font" id="price-field" style="font-size: 24px;">
    <span class="money" style="font-size: 24px;">$50</span>
    </h3>
<h5 class="compare-at-price js hide" style="font-size: 14px;">
    </h5>
 <h3 class="custom-font" id="price-field" style="font-size: 24px;">
    <span class="money" style="font-size: 24px;">$70</span>
    </h3>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `hasClass` function on the child element.

```
if($(".parentclass1").children("p").hasClass("childclass1")) {
   $(".childclass2").css('color', 'red');
}
```

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Comment: I followed as you suggested but no luck. Maybe I missed something:
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
if($(".compare-at-price").children("span").hasClass(".money")) {
   $(".money").css('color', 'red');
}
</script>
</head>

Comment: jquery & related scripts should be placed after the </html> tag